# Can I use manifold learning to transform the feature set as a substitute of graph kernel of SVC

Tags: python, scikit-learn, graphical-model, manifold

I just wonder since the manifold learning under scikit-learn has component of graph-based transformation (e.g. Shortest-path graph search under Isomap) I can then transform the feature data set (i.e. measurements of a chemical physical attributes to decide its toxicity) to something that will measure the graph-based measurements.